# Mean and variance of a random variable whose distribution is Pr {X = k} = Binomial [N-k, n] *Binomial [k-1,n] /Binomial [N, 2n+1] for k=n+1, ..., N-n

Tags: probability, binomial-coefficients

What is the mean and variance of the random variable whose distribution function is

$P(X = k)=$ $\binom{N-k}{ n}  \times \binom{k-1}{n} \over \binom{N}{ 2n+1}$ for $k=n+1, ..., N-n$?

---

*Progress*: Since I could not get Mathematica to give me a nice closed form expression, I took on the simpler task of verifying that the probabilities sum up to 1 over the given range. I tried Identity 5.26 from Concrete Mathematics:   $\sum_{k=0}^l\binom{l-k}{m} \times \binom{q+k}{n} = \binom{l+q+1}{m+n+1}$ but the summation index of my computation does not match that of the said identity.

Comment: I have added latex for you.  If you click over you will see how it is done. What have you tried so people can best help?

Comment: Since I could not get Mathematica to give me a nice closed form expression, I took on the simpler task of verifying that the probabilities sum up to 1 over the given range. I tried Identity 5.25 from Concrete Mathematics: (Learning Latex is on my todo list in the meanwhile) $\sum \binom{l-k}{m} \times \binom{q+k}{n}, k=0..l = \binom{l+q+1}{m+n+1}$ but the summation index of my computation does not match that of the said identity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose we have a random variable $X$ where

$$\mathrm{P}[X=k] = {N\choose 2n+1}^{-1}
{N-k\choose n}{k-1\choose n}$$

for $k=n+1,\ldots, N-n$ and zero otherwise.

We seek  to show that these  probabilities sum to one  and compute the
the mean and the variance.

**Sum of probabilities.**
This is given by
$${N\choose 2n+1}^{-1}
\sum_{k=n+1}^{N-n} {N-k\choose n}{k-1\choose n}.$$

Introduce
$${N-k\choose n}
= \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} 
\frac{1}{z^{N-n-k+1}} \frac{1}{(1-z)^{n+1}} \; dz$$

and
$${k-1\choose n}
= \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} \frac{(1+w)^{k-1}}{w^{n+1}} \; dw.$$

Observe carefully that the first  integral is zero when $k\gt N-n$ and
the second one  when $1\le k\le n$  so we may extend the  range of the
sum to $1\le k.$

This gives for the sum (without the scalar)
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} 
\frac{1}{z^{N-n}} \frac{1}{(1-z)^{n+1}} 
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{w^{n+1}} 
\sum_{k\ge 1} z^{k-1} (1+w)^{k-1}
\; dw\; dz
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} 
\frac{1}{z^{N-n}} \frac{1}{(1-z)^{n+1}} 
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{w^{n+1}} 
\frac{1}{1-z(1+w)}
\; dw\; dz.$$

The integral in $w$ is
$$\frac{1}{1-z} \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{w^{n+1}} 
\frac{1}{1-wz/(1-z)}
\; dw$$

which yields for the integral in $z$
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} 
\frac{1}{z^{N-n}} \frac{1}{(1-z)^{n+1}} 
\frac{z^n}{(1-z)^{n+1}} \; dz$$

which is
$${N-2n-1+2n+1\choose 2n+1} = {N\choose 2n+1}.$$

This confirms that the probabilities sum to one.

**Expectation.**
This is given by
$$\mathrm{E}[X] = {N\choose 2n+1}^{-1}
\sum_{k=n+1}^{N-n} k {N-k\choose n}{k-1\choose n}.$$

Introduce

$$k {k-1\choose n} =
\frac{k!}{n!\times (k-1-n)!} =
(n+1) {k\choose n+1} 
\\ = (n+1) \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} \frac{(1+w)^{k}}{w^{n+2}} \; dw.$$

The range control from this integral produces zero when
$0\le k\le n$ so we may extend the sum to zero,
getting

$$(n+1) 
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} 
\frac{1}{z^{N-n+1}} \frac{1}{(1-z)^{n+1}} 
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{w^{n+2}} 
\sum_{k\ge 0} z^k (1+w)^k
\; dw\; dz.$$

The integral in $w$ is
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{w^{n+2}} 
\frac{1}{1-z(1+w)}
\; dw
\\ = \frac{1}{1-z} \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{w^{n+2}} 
\frac{1}{1-wz/(1-z)}
\; dw$$

which yields for the integral in $z$ including the factor in front
$$(n+1)
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} 
\frac{1}{z^{N-n+1}} \frac{1}{(1-z)^{n+1}} 
\frac{z^{n+1}}{(1-z)^{n+2}} \; dz$$

which is
$$(n+1) {N-2n-1+2n+2\choose 2n+2} = (n+1) {N+1\choose 2n+2}.$$

**Variance.** Start by computing

$$\mathrm{E}[(X+1)X] = {N\choose 2n+1}^{-1}
\sum_{k=n+1}^{N-n} (k+1) k {N-k\choose n}{k-1\choose n}.$$

Introduce

$$(k+1) k {k-1\choose n} =
\frac{(k+1)!}{n!\times (k-1-n)!} \\ =
(n+2) (n+1) {k+1\choose n+2} 
= (n+2) (n+1) \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} \frac{(1+w)^{k+1}}{w^{n+3}} \; dw.$$

The range control from this integral produces zero when
$0\le k\le n$ as before so we may extend the sum to zero,
getting

$$(n+2) (n+1) 
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} 
\frac{1}{z^{N-n+1}} \frac{1}{(1-z)^{n+1}} 
\\ \times \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} \frac{1+w}{w^{n+3}} 
\sum_{k\ge 0} z^k (1+w)^k
\; dw\; dz.$$

The integral in $w$ is

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} \frac{1+w}{w^{n+3}} 
\frac{1}{1-z(1+w)}
\; dw
\\ = \frac{1}{1-z} \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} \frac{1+w}{w^{n+3}} 
\frac{1}{1-wz/(1-z)}
\; dw$$

which yields for the integral in $z$ including the factor in front
$$(n+2) (n+1)
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} 
\frac{1}{z^{N-n+1}} \frac{1}{(1-z)^{n+1}} 
\left(\frac{z^{n+2}}{(1-z)^{n+3}}
+ \frac{z^{n+1}}{(1-z)^{n+2}}\right) \; dz$$

which is
$$(n+2) (n+1)
\left({N-2n-2+2n+3\choose 2n+3}
+ {N-2n-1+2n+2\choose 2n+2} \right)
= (n+2)(n+1)
\left({N+1\choose 2n+3} + {N+1\choose 2n+2}\right).$$

**Simplification for ease of interpretation.**

We get for the expectation
$$\mathrm{E}[X] = (n+1) 
\frac{(N+1)!}{(N-2n-1)! (2n+2)!}
\frac{(N-2n-1)! (2n+1)!}{N!}
\\ = \frac{1}{2} (N+1).$$

We obtain furthermore
$$\mathrm{E}[(X+1)X] = (n+2) (n+1) \\ \times
\left(\frac{(N+1)!}{(N-2n-2)! (2n+3)!}
+ \frac{(N+1)!}{(N-2n-1)! (2n+2)!}\right)
\frac{(N-2n-1)! (2n+1)!}{N!}
\\ = \frac{1}{2} (N+1) (n+2)
\left(\frac{N-2n-1}{2n+3} + 1\right)
\\ = \frac{1}{2} (N+2) (N+1) \frac{n+2}{2n+3}.$$

This yields for the variance
$$\mathrm{Var}[X] = \mathrm{E}[X^2] - \mathrm{E}[X]^2 \\=
\frac{1}{2} (N+2) (N+1) \frac{n+2}{2n+3}
- \frac{1}{2} (N+1) 
- \frac{1}{4} (N+1)^2.$$

which simplifies to
$$\mathrm{Var}[X] = \frac{1}{4} (N+1) \frac{N-2n-1}{2n+3}.$$